# Existence of a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

For each $n\geq 1$ and each choice $u_1, \cdots, u_n \geq 1$, define nonnegative real numbers $p_n(u_1,\cdots, u_n)$ such that $\sum_{k} p_1(k)=1$ and for $n\geq 1$:

$\sum_k p_{n+1}(u_1,\cdots, u_n, k) = p_n(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$.

Show that there exists a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, a probability measure $\mu$ such that

$\mu \{ \omega \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}: \pi_i(\omega)=u_i, i=1,\cdots, n \} = p_n(u_1,\cdots, u_n)$, where $\pi_i (\omega)$ represents the $i^{th}$ coordinate of the sequence $\omega$.

**My attempt:**

I want to apply [Kolmogorov's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem). In this case, $p_n$ represent the probability measure and I need to check the consistency conditions with $p_n$.

I have that for $n\geq 1$, $\sum_k p_{n}(u_1,\cdots, u_n, k)=1$. 
It is possible to define $p_n(\emptyset)=0$ and the missing condition to verify that $p_n$ is a probability (disjoint sets).

Now, in order to use Kolmogorov's extension I need to check

First condition: for all permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$:
\begin{align}
p_n(u_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, u_{\sigma(n)}) &= \sum_k p_{n+1}(u_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, u_{\sigma(n)},k) \\ 
=& \sum_{(u_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, u_{\sigma(n)})\in \mathbb{N}^n} \sum_k p_{n}(u_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, u_{\sigma(n)}) \\ 
&= \sum_{(u_{1}, \cdots, u_{n})\in \mathbb{N}^n} \sum_k p_{n}(u_{1}, \cdots, u_{n}) \\
&= p_n(u_1,\cdots, u_n)
\end{align}

Second condition: for a set $A=\{u_1,\cdots, u_n\}$ I need to verify that:
$p_{n}(u_1,\cdots, u_n) = p_{n+m}(A\times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{N} )$

**Is the second condition true? Is correct to apply the theorem for this problem?** Any help with the second condition is well received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [Ionescu-Tulcea theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionescu-Tulcea_theorem) instead. For each $n\ge 1$, define
$$
\kappa_{n}((u_1,\ldots,u_n),A):=\sum_{k\in A}\frac{p_{n+1}(u_1,\ldots,u_n,k)}{p_n(u_1,\ldots,u_n)}\times 1\{p_n(u_1,\ldots,u_n)>0\},\quad A\subseteq \mathbb{N}.
$$
Also let $P_0(A):=\sum_{k\in A}p_1(k)$.
Then each $\kappa_{n}$ is a Markov kernel and $P_0$ is the initial distribution, and so there exists a probability measure $\mu$ satisfying the required condition.

Comment: Nice! I did not know about this theorem. Do you think my  attempt will not working? Thanks.

Comment: @Hiperion I think that there is no enough information to check the first consistency condition (permutations).